# Facebook signed_request returns NULL

Tags: facebook

I have create new iframe app on facebook and want to detect whether the user is a fan or not of the current page so I use the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] variable as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/. However $_REQUEST['signed_request'] variable always returns NULL, not what it should actually return. Has anyone ever encountered the same problem? I'm quite familiar with creating apps on facebook but can't figure out what could be the reason of this problem... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing any kind of redirection? setting or unsetting the `GET` or `POST` vars?

Comment: Nothing at all! Just printing the value of the variable at the very top of the code for debugging and it returns NULL!

Comment: make sure you have the `signed_request for Canvas` setting enabled in the App Advanced Settings also refer to this [thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91179).

Comment: In your app setting check the page url, check for signed_request variable on the page specified in url

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your Page tab url you specify the name of the page for example http://yourdomain.com/myapp/index.php instead of just http://yourdomain.com/myapp

The signed request only seems to get posted if you specify the exact page

Answer (score -1):

You can use Facebook Query Language (FQL) to check if the current user is a Fan of your page.

```
function userIsFan()
{
    global $page_id, $facebook, $access_token;
    $fql = "SELECT uid from page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id='".$page_id."'";
    $param = array('method' => 'fql.query',
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'query' => $fql,
    'callback' => '');
    $response = $facebook->api($param);
    if (isset($response[0]))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Things to take note of...

me() is a method that automatically gets the user id of the current user.
$page_id should be containing your Facebook Page id that you have specified in fbmain.php

Comment: Where did the thread startes ask for checking likes specifically?

Comment: To check whether a user is a fan of a page, you have to track whether have the person liked the page or not.