# unable to get fan page to check if user has liked this page or not using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I just want to know whether a user has liked page or not and following is my code:

```
    function checkPageLike($fbuid,$token){
    $fqlquery = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = ".$this->config->item('pageId')." and uid=".$fbuid;
    $res = "0";
    try{

        $ret_obj = $this->facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' => $fqlquery,
        ),'get',array('access_token' => $token));
        if(checkArray($ret_obj ) && $ret_obj [0]['uid']){
            $res = "1";
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
    return $res;

}
```

So by using this code I am able to check if our page is in liked by this user or not. And it is working. But one of QA did some thing different may be he didn't gave permissions first time, then he gave permissions, installed app. And our above code wasn't able to get if user has liked the page or not. This user removed the app. then again installed but same problem. He logged in from different machine but still our above code is not able to get if that user has liked page. So I want to know that why can be such problem happened? Is it some problem of app permissions? user settings? or we are using wrong way to check if user has liked the page? Why fql is not able to tell if that user has liked the page or not?if our page is in fan pages of that user or not? It is working fine for other users. It is ambiguous but please tell if you guys have any idea?

thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my notes:

1. You should be using the Graph API user [`likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) connection instead of fql: `/PROFILE_ID/likes/PAGE_ID`
2. Make sure you have the `user_likes` permission
3. Check this [answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4970439/whats-method-for-checking-user-fan-of-a-page-in-graph-api/4971560#4971560) for the above
4. If you are trying to build a fan-gate then you don't even need the user authorization as Facebook will send you the "Fan" status of the user when landing on your page tab. [See here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page/5331541#5331541)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `$fbuid` and `$token` are getting valid values. Also, we need to know whether `$this->config->item('pageId')` is containing the correct pageId to be checked against. You may want to edit your question to include what values are inside them and how you get them.

You can follow a similar example over here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863558/1105497